# How to align lines and automaticaly break the lines if they are too long?

Tags: line-breaking, align

I'm trying to align in LaTeX all equal signs, but I'm encountering a problem. If the line is too long it won't automatically break.

My code at the moment:

```
\begin{align*}
n &= \text{number of days in the support and resistance range;} \\
e &= \text{used for an alternative definition of extrema where a low (high) can be defined as the most recent closing price that is less (greater) than the n previous closing prices;} \\
b &= \text{fixed band multiplicative value;}
\end{align*}
```

Result at the moment:
[image: Result]

What I want to get:

[image: End Result]

So I want the line to automatically break if it's too long and put the new line right under the first line (after the equal sign).

How can I do this?
P.s. Additional: Does somebody also know how much (cm/mm) the "align" command shifts the text vertical down? I don't really want the command to shift the text downwards, and want to correct this with "\vspace{-Xmm}".

Comment: Can you clarify about the text being pushed down? Which text? It is the `\belowdisplayskip` which is the vertical space between the text below and the last line of the equation.

Comment: I think the `\align*` function in combination with my template made the text (box) shifts down (in relation to my header), however such thing won't happen with `\tabularx`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An equation-oriented environment such as `align*` isn't well suited for the task at hand. Instead, consider using a table-like environment such as `tabularx`.

The following code uses the construct `@{${}={}$}` to insert a properly-spaced `=` symbol between the first and second column of the `tabularx` environment; the `X` column type, used for the second column, "wraps" its contents automatically as needed. The overall width of the table is set to `0.75\textwidth` -- adjust this setting as you see fit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{>{$}r<{$} @{${}={}$} X}
  n &number of days in the support and resistance range; \\
  e &used for an alternative definition of extrema where 
     a low (high) can be defined as the most recent closing     
     price that is less (greater) than the n previous closing 
     prices; \\
  b &fixed band multiplicative value.\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is maybe even smarter/faster as the `\align*` command!

Comment: What is the meaning of >{$}r<{$}?

Comment: @fairytale - I will assume that you know that `$` has a special meaning in TeX and LaTeX documents, viz, to initiate and terminate (inline) math mode. The `r` part in `>{$}r<{$}` stands for right-alignment of the cell contents. The `>{$}` and `<{$}` particles serve to inform LaTeX that the cell contents should be processed in (inline) math mode automatically. With this setup, the creator of the table needn't remember to encase the `n`, `e`, and `b` letters in start-math and end-math `$` dollar tokens. I would argue that this makes the table code easier to parse.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
n &= \text{number of days in the support and resistance range;} \\
e &= \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{used for an alternative definition of extrema where a low (high) can be defined as the most recent closing price that is less (greater) than the n previous closing prices;} \\
b &= \text{fixed band multiplicative value;}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]